# How do I add multiple PODs to the end of my perl script?

Tags: perl, documentation, perl-pod

I was working with a tutorial found in the perl documentation about how to use [Getopt::Long](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html) in a script. In there it shows how to add documentation using [Pod::Usage](http://perldoc.perl.org/Pod/Usage.html) rather then having to type everything out a subroutine or something. Anyhow in the example they have this;

```
    GetOptions('help|?' => \$help, 'b|backup' => \&backup, d|discover => \&discover, man => \$man) or pod2usage(2);
pod2usage(1) if $help;
pod2usage(-exitstatus => 0, -verbose => 2) if $man;
```

I added some of my own arguments.

I get how to refer to the first section of documentation. But how do I refer to the second section as stated by `pod2usage(2)`?

When I add a new section after the `=cut` at the end of section 1, when I try to have it display it I am met with a command prompt, like it went in and then out without show the section. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need "multiple PODs".

`pod2usage`, when called as, e.g., `pod2usage(1)`, here the 1 represents the exit status, and the verbosity level is implied as 1, so it will print the `SYNOPSIS`, and any sections titled `OPTIONS`, `ARGUMENTS` or `OPTIONS AND ARGUMENTS`

When called as `pod2usage(-exitval => 0, -verbose => 2)`, it will print the entirety of the POD, within your text pager (identical to what `perldoc yourscriptname.pl` would do) and exit with `0`.  (Note it's `-exitval` and not `-exitstatus`).

It's well-described in the `Pod::Usage` documentation [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/Pod/Usage.html), and works just as described.

You may find the optional `-sections` parameter to `pod2usage` useful for what you have described, combined with `-verbose => 1`, to pick and choose what you wish to display.

Comment: Ok I looked over the Pod::Usage docs more slowly and saw the part that are talking about. The only part I can't seem to get working is the GetOptions..... or pod2usage(2); It just dumps to a prompt, it does not display the menu like it should. Just to see I edited one of the my command flags to do the same thing as pod2usage(2) and it works perfect.

Comment: In your example, none of the options are required options, and as such, `GetOptions` returns true (well, `1`), so the `or pod2usage(2);` clause is never executed.  Has nothing to do with `pod2usage`.

Comment: But doesn't no args = 0? Which would fire the or clause.

Comment: Nope, GetOptions "will return a true value if the command line could be processed successfully. Otherwise, it will write error messages to STDERR, and return a false result."  (From the Getopt::Long documentation).  Since there were no *required* arguments, it was "processed successfully."